# Redis connects remote clients periodically

Tags: redis

I have a weird problem with redis, about once every 30 minutes it disconnects every client. Log out put below. I have neither set maxclients nor does the timeout apply in this case.

Any ideas?

```
[23829] 29 Dec 16:32:09 * DB saved on disk
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:09 * Background saving terminated with success
 ..................... last save ...................
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:11 - DB 0: 71487 keys (0 volatile) in 131072 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:11 - DB 10: 1270390 keys (23754 volatile) in 2097152 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:11 - 240 clients connected (0 slaves), 505148952 bytes in use
.............. everything runs smoothly .............................
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:42 - DB 0: 71487 keys (0 volatile) in 131072 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:42 - DB 10: 1270407 keys (23756 volatile) in 2097152 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:42 - 240 clients connected (0 slaves), 505151288 bytes in use
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:47 - DB 0: 71486 keys (0 volatile) in 131072 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - DB 10: 1270389 keys (23737 volatile) in 2097152 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - 240 clients connected (0 slaves), 505145592 bytes in use
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Client closed connection
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Client closed connection
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Client closed connection

 .......... all 240 clients disconnect here at once ............


[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Client closed connection
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54879

.......... clients start reconnecting

[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Client closed connection
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53152
[1332] 29 Dec 16:32:56 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:33971
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:06 - DB 0: 71489 keys (0 volatile) in 131072 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:06 - DB 10: 1270315 keys (23658 volatile) in 2097152 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:06 - 225 clients connected (0 slaves), 504819848 bytes in use
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:06 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53764
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:06 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53766
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:06 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54940
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:07 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54941
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:09 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54942
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:09 - Accepted xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49227
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:10 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:10 * Background saving started by pid 24057
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:11 - DB 0: 71489 keys (0 volatile) in 131072 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:11 - DB 10: 1270270 keys (23615 volatile) in 2097152 slots HT.
[1332] 29 Dec 16:33:11 - 234 clients connected (0 slaves), 504908696 bytes in use

.....   everything returns to normal, for about 30 minutes .............
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the answer was a cronjob ... but not on the Redis host. I had a different host copy a DB backup ~900MB every 30 minutes to the host which runs redis.

Apparently this caused some kind of problems, I switched the backup to a different host and since then everything runs smoothly.